# Unlimited billing tier on trial period Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I did a trial period for BigQuery and have been testing it out, but I checked the allow unlimited box for a query with a bad join and it wound up being billing tier 251 for 14GB, which is way over the $300 they give you. It hasn't shown up in my billing though so I'm not sure if this is covered by the free TB each month or if I'm going to discover a $17,000 bill at some point. How does this work? I am very worried

Comment: job id available? and what kind of query was that? (oh, one with an explosive join)

Comment: job id: bquijob_4ff0b12b_1540b891362

Comment: Investigating! In any case don't worry too much: If you are using a free trial account, you won't be charged at all, until you press the button to "graduate" from free trial. Also if you have only 14GB and a multiplier of 251, that would cost $18 (not even close to $17,000... 251* 14GB * $5/terabyte)

Comment: Oh, awesome. For some reason I thought it was $5 a GB. Thanks